# Livedata is not triggered when List item is getting updated

Tags: kotlin, android-livedata, observers, mutablelivedata, mutablelist

I have a pretty straightforward question about LiveData. I have a `MutableLiveData<MutableList<Car>>` and I want to update a specific field in my list, so I guess that when the field is updated, the MutableLiveData should trigger the observers but that does not happen.

So if I use this line of code my observers are not triggered.

```
var carList = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Car>>()
...
carList.value?.set(car.id,Car(car.id, color))
```

But if I do something like this the observers are triggered.

```
var carList = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Car>>()
...
var newList = carList.value
carList?.set(car.id,Car(car.id, color))
carList.value = newList
```

Can please somebody explain why this happens? Is it essential to give a whole new list to the livedata to be triggered or there is something I am missing? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assign a new `MutableList` to the wrapped value of `MutableLiveData` then it will notify its observers but if you add/delete any items of its wrapped value it will not notify its observers because the wrapped value has same `MutableList` object reference. Thus your second case is notifying where your first case does not notify. You can overcome this problem by making an extension of `MutableLiveData` as follows:

```
fun <T> MutableLiveData<MutableList<T>>.addNewItem(item: T) {
    val oldValue = this.value ?: mutableListOf()
    oldValue.add(item)
    this.value = oldValue
}

fun <T> MutableLiveData<MutableList<T>>.addNewItemAt(index: Int, item: T) {
    val oldValue = this.value ?: mutableListOf()
    oldValue.add(index, item)
    this.value = oldValue
}

fun <T> MutableLiveData<MutableList<T>>.removeItemAt(index: Int) {
    if (!this.value.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        val oldValue = this.value
        oldValue?.removeAt(index)
        this.value = oldValue
    } else {
        this.value = mutableListOf()
    }
}
```

Then add/remove items from your `MutableLiveData` like:

```
// Here is your car list
var carList = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Car>>()

// Add new item to your car list
carList.addNewItem(Car(car.id, color))

// Delete an item from car list at position i
carList.removeItemAt(i)

// Add new item to your car list at position i
carList.addNewItemAt(i, Car(car.id, color))
```

Comment: I see ...So it is not possible to trigger the observers just by update a field in the already existed list...

Comment: @Konstantinos.T No, it is not possible but if `Android Authority` make it possible in future then we can do it in future. Thank you

Comment: Can't we just use something like `var carList = MutableList<Car>()` instead of `var carList = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Car>>()`

Comment: Oh, I see. `MutableList` is not designed for `LiveData` at all. It is just a thread-safe List. Thank you for sharing simple implementation of something that I would call `LiveDataCollection`

Comment: @Kamil Yeah! you already got it brother.